# how to write code for this?

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx, spartan

In Verilog HDL describe a hardware that is able to generate a clock frequency f 0 of approximately 3Hz. Display this clock by connecting it to LED LD7 to verify your approach.
I tried a lot but not able to get right output.

Device:-Basys2 Spartan3e

Comment: what did you try? Post it here. Well be able to help

Comment: Also you must have an input clock of some frequency?

Answer (score 1):

I will give the steps(not the code) to create a clock divider which is what you need here.

1. Say you clock has frequency f. Create a counter which counts from 1 to f/2.
2. Say your new divided clock name is clk_new. Initialize this clk_new to zero.
3. Whenever the counter value is in its maximum (which is f/2), toggle clk_new.
   you can do this by clk_new = ~clk_new;
   and also reset the counter to zero and let it begin the counting again.

Write the code and if it doesnt work, post here. We can help.